# Sinch framework (Objective C) and Swift not compatible

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Sinch SDK ([link](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/)) which is written in Objective C.

But I am making a Swift application. I created bridge header and I added some basic functionality in the view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SINMessageClientDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initializeSinch()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func initializeSinch()
    {
        // Instantiate a Sinch client object
        let sinchClient = Sinch.clientWithApplicationKey("xxxxxxxxxxxx", applicationSecret: "xxxxxxxxxx", environmentHost: "sandbox.sinch.com", userId: "user1")
        sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true)
        sinchClient.start()

        let messageClient = sinchClient.messageClient()

        let message = SINOutgoingMessage(recipient: "user2", text: "Test 123, test 123")
        messageClient.sendMessage(message)
    }

    // Tells the delegate that a message has been received.
    func messageClient(messageClient: SINMessageClient, didReceiveIncomingMessage message: SINMessage) {
        // Present a Local Notification if app is in background
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Background {
            var notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.alertBody = "Message from \(message.recipientIds[0])"
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
        }
        else {
            // Update UI in-app
        }

    }

    // Tells the delegate that a message for a specific recipient has been sent by the local user.
    func messageSent(message: SINMessage, recipientId: String) {
//        var a = 1
    }
//
    // Tells the delegate that a message has been delivered (to a particular recipient).
    func messageDelivered(info: SINMessageDeliveryInfo) {
//        var a = 1
    }

    func messageFailed(message: SINMessage, info messageFailureInfo: SINMessageFailureInfo) {
//        var a = 1
    }

}
```

This is how the error looks like.
[image: Error log]

Can someone advice how can I fix this?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added all the neccesary frameworks, and the linker flags?

```
AudioToolbox.framework
AVFoundation.framework
Security.framework
```

Some additional linker flags need to be added. In the Build Settings pane for the application target, set the following:

```
Other Linker Flags -> -ObjC -Xlinker -lc++
```

https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/